# Bootstrap 5 - overlay navbar and push content from the top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm looking to have the 'non-collapsed' navbar menu overlayed on the `. basically a navigation overtop a large main image. However, when the menu is collapsed, I want it to push all the content from the top of the page. Where the default nav pushes the content from below the navbar.

html

Navbar

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggleExternalContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</nav>
</header>

<div id="bg-img" class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div id="main-wrap" class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#bg-img {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 75vh;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hey, I think I am looking for something similar. But your formulation is a bit confusing. Consider making it more clear, so people can answer you :)